# generic curve fitting by changing model function in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am using SciPy.optimize.curve_fit https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html
to get the coefficients of curve fitting function, the SciPy function takes the model function as its first argument
so if I want to make a linear curve fit, I pass to it the following function:

```
def objective(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b
```

If I want polynomial curve fitting of second degree, I pass the following:

```
def objective(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c
```

And so on, what I want to achieve is to make this model function generic
for example, if the user wanted to curve fit to a polynomial of 5th degree by inputting 5 it should change to

```
def objective(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    return (a * x) + (b * x**2) + (c * x**3) + (d * x**4) + (e * x**5) + f
```

While the code is running
is this possible?
And if it is not possible using SciPy because it requires to change a function, is there any other way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to implement it on your own, you can either use a variable number of coefficients `*coeffs`:

```py
def objective(x, *coeffs):
    result = coeffs[-1]
    for i, coeff in enumerate(coeffs[:-1]):
        result += coeff * x**(i+1)
    return result
```

or use [`np.polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html):

```py
import numpy as np

def objective(x, *coeffs):
    return np.polyval(x, coeffs)
```

However, note that there's no need to use `curve_fit`. You can directly use [`np.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to do a least-squares polynomial fit.

Comment: works really well thanks

Answer (score 1):

The task can be accomplished in a few ways. If you want to use scipy, you can simply create a dictionary to refer to specific function by using numerical input from user:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimization
polnum = 2 # suppose this is input from user


def objective1(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b


def objective2(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c

# Include some more functions

# Do not include round brackets in the dictionary 
object_dict = {
    1: objective1,
    2: objective2
# Include the numbers with corresponding functions
}
opt = optimization.curve_fit(object_dict[polnum], x, y)  # Curve fitted

print(opt[0]) # Returns parameters
```

However, I would suggest you going with a bit better way where you do not have to define each function:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

polnum = 2  # suppose this is input from user

# Creates a Polynomial of polnum degree
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(polnum), LinearRegression)
# You can change the estimator Linear Regression to any other offered in sklearn.linear_model
# Make sure that x and y data are of the same shape
model.fit(x, y)
# Now you can use the model to check some other values
y_predict = model.predict(x_predict[:, np.newaxis])
```

Comment: i want to ask about the "x_predict[:, np.newaxis]" what does this do?, in another words what do i put in model.predict()

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad, I was not suppose to include it there. However, I may try to explain the occasions when you can do so. Suppose that you have a lot of data and you want to split it into 2 part: 1st one to train a model and the second one is to check whether model is correct. So, you will have 2 batches x_train + y train and x_test + y_test. Obviously, you train you data on x_train + y train and you test your data by using the model with input of x_test and get values of y_predict. Then you compare y_predict and y_test to see if the model is good enough. Hope you can understand it!